# how to check whether a button is on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any javascript property to check whether a button is on hover. This i need because when the mouse is already hovered on the button i would to perform a particular task.

I can see event onMouseOver but no property to check whether mouse is hovered or not.

Can any one please help me out on how i can proceed with this.

Comment: You could set a variable / attribute on the element to `true` on `onMouseOver` and `false` on `onMouseOut`. This way, you can check the attribute of an element at any time to check whether the mouse is currently hovering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (jQuery). It's messy but you get the idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/sRsK3/1/

```
<input type="text" value="test"><input type="button" value="test">

<div id="div">-</div>
```

with:

```
$(function(){
    $('*')
        .data('hovering', false)
        .mouseover(function(){$(this).data('hovering', true)})
        .mouseout(function(){$(this).data('hovering', false)});
   });

window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#div').html("Textbox currently hovered: " +
                   $('input[type="text"]').data('hovering'));
}, 100)
```

Comment: hovering isn't a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: You're correct, but who cares? It works beautifully to be honest.

Comment: W3C cares. You could add hovering as a class and use `.addClass`, `.removeClass` and `.hasClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JQuery's Hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I know you didnt tag this question as jQuery. but it does offer [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover) as an event

Comment: `.hover()` is a function that wires event handlers rather than an event.

Answer (score -1):

`onMouseOver` triggers an event, you could set a variable and then read the variable state from other parts of your code. For simplicity, I'd also suggest using [jQuery's "hover" event](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: `.hover()` is a function that wires event handlers rather than an event.